# Passing parameter to sub report in crystal report in vb..net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am calling a report which contains sub report RepHeaderSub.rpt and I want to pass value to parameter in
subreport. I used the below code, but it is giving error 'Index was outside the bound of the array'
in line of passing parameter to sub report. Kindly help me to correct

```
            Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
            cryRpt.Load(appPath & "\Reports\ConsumableLPO.rpt")
            cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "dbr123")
            frmRptViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
            cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@Companyname", "ABC Company", "RepHeaderSub.rpt")

            cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{vComsumableLPO.lpono} ='" & txtLpoNo.Text & "'"

            frmRptViewer.Show()
            frmRptViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Comment: May you post the stack trace? Is there a parameter named Companyname in the subreport RepHeaderSub.rpt? Is the case correct? Any chance of a mispell? Could it be CompanyName?

Comment: Companyname parameter is there in sub report

Comment: Does RepHeaderSub.rpt exists as a separate file? May you try to crete the parameter 'Companyname' in the main report and makes the main report repass it to the subreport? Then you would have to change the code to  cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@Companyname", "ABC Company", "\Reports\ConsumableLPO.rpt") or something like that.